# Angular2 Filter Data From List

Tags: angular, typescript

I am developing angular2 application with typescript.
I need to filter Users by corresponding to  input text box.

**Table after filtering data**

[Input text box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGyTB.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAls7.png)

HTML Table view `users.html`

```
<tr *ngFor='let user of Users'>
        <td>
            <img [src]='user.imageUrl' [title]='user.userName' [style.width.px]='imageWidth' [style.margin.px]='imageMargin'>
        </td>
        <td>{{ user.userName }}</td>
    </tr>
```

User List   `user-list.componet.ts`

```
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {
    imageWidth: number = 50;
    imageMargin: number = 2;
    users: User[] = [
        {
            "productId": 2,
            "productName": "Njjosgaaj",
        }
    ];

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log('In OnInit');
    }
}
```

User Interface `user.ts`

```
export interface User {
    userId: number;
    userName: string;

}
```

I tried to develop this using angular2 custom pipe.
I am wondering about development?
What is the best way of development this feature?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please check how to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask So show us some code, what you have tried and where you have failed, thanks! :)

Comment: you need to post some of your own code for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use angular custom pipe for filter users.

Try to add this kind of filter your code.

Create new file as  `user-filter.ts` add these code

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

import { User } from './user';

@Pipe({
    name: 'productFilter'
})
export class UserFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: User[], filterBy: string): User[] {
        filterBy = filterBy ? filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
        return filterBy ? value.filter((user: User) =>
            user.userName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1) : value;
    }
}
```

Add  `listFilter` attribute to UserListComponent

```
 export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {

        listFilter: string = 'cart';
        --------------
    }
```

Change HTML view

```
<tr *ngFor='let user of Users | userFilter:listFilter '>
        <td>
            <img [src]='user.imageUrl' [title]='user.userName' [style.width.px]='imageWidth' [style.margin.px]='imageMargin'>
        </td>
        <td>{{ user.userName }}</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Using pipe for filtering is not recommended. See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#no-filter-pipe.